# Dataplicity on the Pi

Tags: ssh, remote

When I download the code from Dataplicity (dashes added to hide key):

```
sudo curl https://www.dataplicity.com/-------.py | sudo python
```

it starts downloading until I get:

> The installer was unable to install Supervisor on your system.
>   This may be temporary, you could try again.

Has anyone used Dataplicity and can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And then try installing supervisor manually before you install dataplicity to see if you get any errors:

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```